# Programming Practices: Typecasting array to object

Tags: design-patterns

I just read about 
[Top Bad Practices in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php) and became curious if what I'm doing is also a bad practice...

I usually typecast an array to object

```
$person = (object)$person;
```

just because I prefer typing

```
$person->name
```

than

```
$person['name']
```

Note: I'm not dealing with multi-dimensional arrays when I use this approach.

Need expert advice so I can stop if this is a bad practice :( Thanks Guys!

Comment: You mean *$person['name']* and not *$person->['name']*, right?

Comment: Woops did not see that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not bad practice. As a matter of fact, it's even on the PHP page as a published example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting

There are plenty of legitimate uses, also (your example is a bit capricious); for example:

```
$result = (object)mysql_fetch_assoc();
```

is faster than

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object();
```

Comment: Hmmm guess I should do it that way... Just what I needed to know. Thanks David!

Answer (score 1):

Well, while this does not work with multidimensional arrays as already reported by you, it's not a bad practice.

However you should note that a lot of cases, like [this](http://atomized.org/2009/02/really-damn-slow-a-look-at-php-objects/) and [this](http://aggregation.novaak.net/?q=node/227) reports that arrays are a bit faster than objects in PHP5, very much faster in PHP4. Keep this in mind while making a huge number of iterations.

Comment: +1 For the links and the reminder. Thanks Ingo for pointing it out^^